# Can't open applications on Ubuntu with XRDP from Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xrdp

I have installed XRDP onto an Ubuntu Server system, and I am able to log in. After connecting, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7ERA.png) (which might be useful to help describe the problem.) I then log in using my credentials (jacklyn + my password), and get a [normal looking screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nskSl.png). However, I am unable to open any applications. I'm able to Alt+F2 and run xterm, which works, and try running what I want to run from there (in this instance, `firefox`.) I get this message:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :10.0
```

As seen in other questions, I have tried the command `export DISPLAY=0:0` and I get a different message:

```
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: 0:0
Error: cannot open display: 0:0
```

Additional debugging info: The system's firewall is completely disabled. Running `htop` in xterm works, but starting it from my desktop does not work.

With this information hopefully helping, how may I further debug/fix my system? I'd like to be able to open windows but sadly I haven't been able to fix this with hours of research and debugging.